# Run Wamp and MySQL on the same machine

Tags: windows-7, window

I am creating a website in drupal which I need to install wamp and also creating an online portal using ASP.NET which need to install MySQL separately. How do I make sure the two MySQL are running on the same machine because I need the to run separately. The main MySQL is preventing the MySQL in the wamp from running.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the two mysql processes try to use the same port and that one of those two can't proceed since the other is already using standard port 3306.

So, changing the port at one of those two might help.

Answer (score 0):

During installing MySQL separately, from advanced option [change MySQL instance service name and port](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-windows-services.html)